# Laravel - Controller call Repository in app

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, repository

i'm tring laravel Modules and Repository.I had created Repository in App and Controller in module. But when controller call Repository it report "ReflectionException
Class Modules\Product\Http\Controllers\ProductEntryRepository does not exist".

But ProductEntryRepository in App\Reppsitory but it error in Controlller.
[image]

```
namespace Modules\Product\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller;

use \App\Repositories\ProductCategoryRepository;
use \App\Repositories\ProductCategoryEntryRepository;

class ProductCategoryController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @var PostRepository
     */
    protected $request;
    protected $product_category;
    protected $product_category_entry;

    public function __construct(Request $request, ProductCategoryRepository $product_category, ProductEntryRepository $product_category_entry){
        $this->request = $request;
        $this->product_category = $product_category;
        $this->product_category_entry = $product_category_entry;
    }

    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     * @return Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return view('product::index');
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You should just add `use \App\Repositories\ProductEntryRepository;` at the top of your controller :)

```
namespace Modules\Product\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller;

use \App\Repositories\ProductCategoryRepository;
use \App\Repositories\ProductCategoryEntryRepository;
use \App\Repositories\ProductEntryRepository;

class ProductCategoryController extends Controller
{
  //......
}
```

Or i think you mean `ProductCategoryEntryRepository` not `ProductEntryRepository` in the construct !!

```
public function __construct(Request $request, ProductCategoryRepository $product_category, ProductCategoryEntryRepository $product_category_entry){
    $this->request = $request;
    $this->product_category = $product_category;
    $this->product_category_entry = $product_category_entry;
}
```

Comment: Can i call repository class from any App\Http\Resources class?

Comment: Yes you can call it Laravel will resolve the dependence for you ;)